# Regex to identify specific strings and not just keys

Tags: javascript

I am creating a calculator for my website and I am using the eval()
function, the issue is that I have a whitelist of allowed terms and
keys and I want to make sure only terms that are specifically in that
order are let through. For example, if I have a term called SQRT, I
would like terms that are only SQRT to be let through, right now I
have the problem that all instances of the letters in SQRT are also
let through, for example T

```
var input1 = "0";
var keywords = ["sqrt", "sin", "cos", "tan", "log","exp"];
function evalue(){
    var keys = [];
    keywords.forEach(element => {
        keys.push("{^"+ element +"$}");
    });
    var whitelist = new RegExp("[^-()/1234567890*+." + keys.join() + "]", "g"); 
    input1 = document.getElementById("calcInput1").value;
    input1 = input1.replace(whitelist, '');
    keywords.forEach(element => {
        var elSearch = new RegExp(element, "g");
        input1 = input1.replace(elSearch, "Math."+element)
    });
    input1 = eval(input1);
    input1 = (Math.round((input1*100)))/100;
    document.getElementById("calcResult").innerHTML=input1;
    console.log(input1);
}
```

I thought that by separating the terms into `{^$}`, they would only find those specific terms and let them through.

Comment: Something that could come handy: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[^xxxx]` is not character inside, if you put there any word it will use characters from the word.

I would solve your problem with tokenizing the string using the keywords and numbers and filtering out what don't match:

```js
var keywords = ["sqrt", "sin", "cos", "tan", "log","exp"];
var re = new RegExp('(' + keywords.join('|') + '|[0-9]+)');
var input = document.querySelector('input');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var text = input.value.split(re).filter(Boolean).map(function(token) {
    if (token.match(re)) {
      return token;
    }
    return '';
  }).join('');
  console.log(text);
});
```

```html
<input/>
<button>eval</button>
```

And suggestion if you want proper calculator you probably will need a parser, you can use some parser generator. I've wrote an article about different parser generators in JS (but it's in Polish), there are example codes and you can use google translate (link with translation). [5 parser generators in JavaScript](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=pl&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fjcubic.pl%2F2017%2F11%2Fparsery-i-generatory-parserow-w-javascript.html) (here is original post [5 Parserów i Generatorów Parserów w JavaScript](https://jcubic.pl/2017/11/parsery-i-generatory-parserow-w-javascript.html) use this link to check the example source code, because Google was converting the code into one line).